# Why test file can't run tests against app file?

Tags: unit-testing, flask, flask-testing

I'm practising tdd with Flask and funny enough my first test file
can't seem to detect the main flask_app file:

test_basics.py :

```
from flask_testing import TestCase
from flask_app import app
import unittest


class TestBasics(TestCase):

    def test_home_route(self):
        with self.client:
            response = self.client.get('/')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertTrue(response.data == b'hakuna matata')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I created `setup.py` so the root directory is treated as a project directory:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages


setup(
    version='0.0.1',
    description='training',
    name='flask'
)
```

project structure:

```
├── flask_app.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── flask_app.cpython-38.pyc
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── test_basics.py
└── venv


export FLASK_APP=flask_app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

What do I need to do so the tests can run against the main flask_app.py file ?

`python tests/test_basics.py` returns:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'`

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of `Flask-Testing` before.

I would strongly suggest to follow the official documentation.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/